# What is the efficient way to sort custom fields in django models?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I load all the leads, iterate the queryset and populate the custom fields.
The custom fields are dependent on other model.

Then I sort the leads  by these custom fields and show the result.

This method is very slow.

How can I optimize and increase speed?

The models are as follows

**Lead Model**

```
class Lead(LeadModel):


  def most_recent_mailing_date(self):
    """ Return the most recent mailing date """
    mailingHistories = self.mailinghistory_set.all()
    if len(mailingHistories) != 0:
        today = datetime.date.today()

        mostRecentHistory = None
        diff = -1
        for mailingHistory in mailingHistories:
            if mailingHistory.mailing_date < today and (diff == -1 or (today - mailingHistory.mailing_date) < diff):
                mostRecentHistory = mailingHistory
                diff = today - mostRecentHistory.mailing_date

        if mostRecentHistory is None:
            return "No Mailing History"
        else:
            return mostRecentHistory.mailing_date
    else:
        return "No Mailing History"


  def next_mailing_date(self):
    """ Return the next mailing date """
    mailingHistories = self.mailinghistory_set.all()
    if len(mailingHistories) != 0:
        today = datetime.date.today()

        nextHistory = None
        diff = -1
        for mailingHistory in mailingHistories:
            if mailingHistory.mailing_date > today and (diff == -1 or (mailingHistory.mailing_date - today) < diff):
                nextHistory = mailingHistory
                diff = mailingHistory.mailing_date - today

        if nextHistory is None:
            return "No Future Mailings"
        else:
            return nextHistory.mailing_date
    else:
        return "No Future Mailings"
```

**Mailing History Model**

```
class MailingHistory(models.Model):

  lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead)
  returned_envelope = models.BooleanField()
  mailing_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Leads to list function**

```
def leads_to_list(queryset):
holder = []
for item in queryset:
    item_dict = item.__dict__



    recent_mailing_date = item.most_recent_mailing_date()
    next_mailing_date = item.next_mailing_date()

    if not type(recent_mailing_date) == datetime.date:
        recent_mailing_date_key = NONE_DATE
    else:
        recent_mailing_date_key = recent_mailing_date

    if not type(next_mailing_date) == datetime.date:
        next_mailing_date_key = NONE_DATE
    else:
        next_mailing_date_key = next_mailing_date


    item_dict['recent_mailing_date'] = recent_mailing_date
    item_dict['recent_mailing_date_key'] = recent_mailing_date_key
    item_dict['next_mailing_date'] = next_mailing_date
    item_dict['next_mailing_date_key'] = next_mailing_date_key

    if '_state' in item_dict:
        del item_dict['_state']


    holder.append(item_dict)

return holder
```

**Sorting Logic**

```
# Code to be optimized #

leads = Lead.objects.all()
leads = queryset_to_list(leads)   # Important for serialization. json.dumps

sort_key = 'recent_mailing_date_key'
sort_reverse =  True
leads = sorted(leads,key=itemgetter(sort_key),reverse = sort_reverse)

 return json.dumps(leads)
```

Comment: So what's the function you need to profile? Or which code seems slow?

Comment: Do you just need to do `lead_object.mailinghistory_set.order_by('-mailing_date')`? If no, please add more details about what you want to do.

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter, limit and order by in query.
Be careful with len of queryset. The function len counts objects of a list. It is more efficient to use count (function that runs a query to count).

I hope I've helped.

```
class Lead(LeadModel):


def most_recent_mailing_date(self):
   """ Return the most recent mailing date """
   today = datetime.date.today()
   mailingHistories = self.mailinghistory_set.filter(mailing_date__lt=today).order_by('-mailing_date', '-id')[:1]

   if len(mailingHistories) != 0:
       return mostRecentHistory[0].mailing_date
   else:
       return "No Mailing History"


def next_mailing_date(self):
    """ Return the next mailing date """
    today = datetime.date.today()
    mailingHistories = self.mailinghistory_set.filter(mailing_date__gt=today).order_by('mailing_date', 'id')[:1]

    if len(mailingHistories) != 0:
        return mostRecentHistory[0].mailing_date
    else:
        return "No Future Mailings"
```